# About graph of $r=\sin (2 \theta) $ in polar coordinates

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, polar-coordinates

In polar coordinates, for $(r,\theta)$ given point, we know that $r$ defined on $r\geq 0$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $. Because $r$ shows the distance between the point and the origin. My question about graph of $r=\sin (2 \theta)$. For example if $\theta = 3\pi /4$ then $r=-1$ undefined. But in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D+%5Csin(2+theta)), the equation is defined for $\theta = 3\pi /4$. Moreover, for $$ \pi /2 \leq \theta < \pi , \qquad \sin 2\theta <0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad r<0$$ Hence $r$ is undefined. But, wolfram can draw the graph.

Where is the miskate?

[image: polar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With polar coordinates $(r,\theta) $, we have cartesians by

$$x=r\cos (\theta) $$
and
$$y=r\sin (\theta) $$

so $r $ can take negative values.

for example, if $\theta=\frac {3\pi}{4} $,
$r=-1$ and this gives the point

$$(x,y)=(\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2},-\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}) .$$

Comment: For a point $(x,y)$ in cartesian koordinates, $r$ defined $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. In wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: ok but here, you have $r (\theta) $ which defines $(x,y) $.

Comment: cause $y=-\sin (\frac {3\pi}{4}) $.

Comment: Ok, $r \neq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Isn't it?

Comment: All we can say is $$r^2=x^2+y^2$$ without square root.

Comment: Some textbook, such as A First Course in Calculus by Serge Lang, requires that $r\geq 0$.